# Window scroll event in JQuery is not triggered with div element in position fixed and overflow scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Why window scroll is not detected with elements in position fixed if there's in css the `overflow: scroll;` property?

If the condition it's this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    #a {
      position: fixed;
      background: red;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    #aa {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    #b {
      top: 100px;
      position: fixed;
      overflow: scroll;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      /* height is setted with JS but for simulate it's setted manually */
      height: 500px;
      -webkit-transition: top 0.3s;
    }
    
    #c {
      /* height is setted with JS */
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script>
    $("*").on("scroll", function(e) {
      console.log("scrolling");
    })
    $("window").on("scroll", function(e) {
      console.log("scrolling");
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div id="a">
      <div id="aa">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>



  <main>
    <div id="b">
      <div id="c">
        F&1W8xyaOkA1ksfM9Dp
        <br> q2%aKsbDUlE1@GvE4v
        <br> XKCMcpA4bxmGpZIPAT0
        <br> cxL0tQ5t7zt!b&rVNL!
        <br> v3@6LANuuQ^n1swb)6c
        <br> L6o&6llTkqLGOuh(oug
        <br> CoDDa76!bkDw2Hn%ZCX
        <br> uuGcqIr(bVPHR*^!v&y
        <br> Ld&q&Y9G@w5XZKZcARL
        <br> 5k1!eJmacWe5kJbDj!r
        <br> HTSRtSTAKCDEy2MjK*c
        <br> Nq^&cTlUcan&oSDNGtc
        <br> P%J(LRZHir7d7iPVfN7
        <br> chbGfzkrxI2eXvCszH2
        <br> yl1dMbEQ4ycI5R4U&1
        <br> 5h42cd8XxOCcGdk)fCw
        <br> mEniGshHPHsTSMV9Zi
        <br> )1Yk!&VrFlqt(pEOSl6
        <br> s!enwOf@7RCErVgfG0s
        <br> Rks!cx!Y(5ixDX()R
        <br> 7ZxOmEeJYmHcoQkv4BC
        <br> FneHbodv*wS)*Q7a*A&
        <br> 4T4!D*J5^V9L&UHoiB
        <br> fnHgaK!1D6Slm)TO&MF
        <br> fBV%%4)H0i6stle)EFg
        <br> *aa&w%D9aS@1NbO(GS9
        <br> b!zwIVJtv4Ihi!%6XGj
        <br> 34)fvxWYpB3Alovj^1)
        <br> 4HvY5MmeUaOaf&Kktl
        <br> 6zIdvB(@lTiXwQzgB^Y
        <br> HkcQ*U5xNl(E6z5@l
        <br> ByM6jeZjGl%2K7Wv!HM
        <br> 4OSC*HcGW9gJ@E%MS5E
        <br> kNZ9WdbpHx3gqecIjqn
        <br> vayBp^o7^8NdztFVySS
        <br> AO&diq^*Y3PnyEand!r
        <br> YgVu@GHQhxbCsH73I56
        <br> T^0KLQwScvig)okXwKN
        <br> G94(ScoX&U5XA9o1cgI
        <br> r&^xZLvawH)^1qETka0
        <br> LWHs%*TX!PBiPwPDsnt
        <br> QZTDpVCwwGyxCk7s6pd
        <br> 6NO8a8vpJmbf*Cc^%c2
        <br> zmkIrV@XJxaywe7f^V&
        <br> rREWV&3vrBdb(1wWTav
        <br> df*z83KfPilOJhQD8vP
        <br> AZil1GPzZxq5U6!SDJg
        <br> eoW6Q2gm1kDw251W(Nx
        <br> S66wLAW6X1(0zfQ5W2
        <br> mAs54R9q1inHMkU6(4E
      </div>
      
      
      <footer>
        <center><h2>Footer</h2></center>
      </footer>
      
    </div>
    
  </main>
  <nav>
    position fixed (left side with JS)
  </nav>
  <script>
      document.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(element => element.addEventListener("scroll", ({
      target
    }) => console.log('Scrolling ', target, target.id)));
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

why `querySelectorAll("*")` logs the scroll and JQuery does not logging the scrolling?

**How to detect the scroll with the current layout in JQuery**?

---

Edit (to better understand):

**How to detect the scroll with the current layout in JQuery at the beginning of the file?**

Answer (score 0):

The scroll event is not being detected for the window because the scrolling happens with the div. The window is not scrolling, only the div.

The reason your other code that adds adds the scroll event listener to each element isn't picking up the event either, is because it is placed in the head of the document before any of the elements.

In the following code, I moved that part of your script to the bottom.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      #a {
        position: fixed;
        background: red;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
      }

      #aa {
        display: inline-block;
      }

      #b {
        top: 100px;
        position: fixed;
        overflow: scroll;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        /* height is setted with JS but for simulate it's setted manually */
        height: 500px;
        -webkit-transition: top 0.3s;
      }

      #c {
        /* height is setted with JS */
      }

    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(window).on("scroll", function(e) {
        console.log("scrolling");
      })

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <header>
      <div id="a">
        <div id="aa">
          <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>



    <main>
      <div id="b">
        <div id="c">
          F&1W8xyaOkA1ksfM9Dp
          <br> q2%aKsbDUlE1@GvE4v
          <br> XKCMcpA4bxmGpZIPAT0
          <br> cxL0tQ5t7zt!b&rVNL!
          <br> v3@6LANuuQ^n1swb)6c
          <br> L6o&6llTkqLGOuh(oug
          <br> CoDDa76!bkDw2Hn%ZCX
          <br> uuGcqIr(bVPHR*^!v&y
          <br> Ld&q&Y9G@w5XZKZcARL
          <br> 5k1!eJmacWe5kJbDj!r
          <br> HTSRtSTAKCDEy2MjK*c
          <br> Nq^&cTlUcan&oSDNGtc
          <br> P%J(LRZHir7d7iPVfN7
          <br> chbGfzkrxI2eXvCszH2
          <br> yl1dMbEQ4ycI5R4U&1
          <br> 5h42cd8XxOCcGdk)fCw
          <br> mEniGshHPHsTSMV9Zi
          <br> )1Yk!&VrFlqt(pEOSl6
          <br> s!enwOf@7RCErVgfG0s
          <br> Rks!cx!Y(5ixDX()R
          <br> 7ZxOmEeJYmHcoQkv4BC
          <br> FneHbodv*wS)*Q7a*A&
          <br> 4T4!D*J5^V9L&UHoiB
          <br> fnHgaK!1D6Slm)TO&MF
          <br> fBV%%4)H0i6stle)EFg
          <br> *aa&w%D9aS@1NbO(GS9
          <br> b!zwIVJtv4Ihi!%6XGj
          <br> 34)fvxWYpB3Alovj^1)
          <br> 4HvY5MmeUaOaf&Kktl
          <br> 6zIdvB(@lTiXwQzgB^Y
          <br> HkcQ*U5xNl(E6z5@l
          <br> ByM6jeZjGl%2K7Wv!HM
          <br> 4OSC*HcGW9gJ@E%MS5E
          <br> kNZ9WdbpHx3gqecIjqn
          <br> vayBp^o7^8NdztFVySS
          <br> AO&diq^*Y3PnyEand!r
          <br> YgVu@GHQhxbCsH73I56
          <br> T^0KLQwScvig)okXwKN
          <br> G94(ScoX&U5XA9o1cgI
          <br> r&^xZLvawH)^1qETka0
          <br> LWHs%*TX!PBiPwPDsnt
          <br> QZTDpVCwwGyxCk7s6pd
          <br> 6NO8a8vpJmbf*Cc^%c2
          <br> zmkIrV@XJxaywe7f^V&
          <br> rREWV&3vrBdb(1wWTav
          <br> df*z83KfPilOJhQD8vP
          <br> AZil1GPzZxq5U6!SDJg
          <br> eoW6Q2gm1kDw251W(Nx
          <br> S66wLAW6X1(0zfQ5W2
          <br> mAs54R9q1inHMkU6(4E
        </div>


        <footer>
          <center>
            <h2>Footer</h2>
          </center>
        </footer>

      </div>

    </main>
    <nav>
      position fixed (left side with JS)
    </nav>
    <script>
      document.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(element => element.addEventListener("scroll", ({
        target
      }) => console.log('Scrolling ', target)));

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: "The reason your other code that adds adds the scroll event listener to each element isn't picking up the event either, is because it is placed in the head of the document before any of the elements." **This was edited before you write** "The scroll event is not being detected for the window because the scrolling happens with the div. The window is not scrolling, only the div." **There's also `$("*").on("scroll", function(e) {` that does not catches the log** Some ideas Luke☀️?

Comment: @user20417316, Could you clarify what you are trying to say?

Comment: "Could you clarify what you are trying to say?" Nothing more clear then this: `$("*").on("scroll", function(e) { console.log("scrolling"); })` it's not logging, but `querySelectorAll("*")` logs everything. Why this behavior? P.S. The code u edited it was edited before you write. Always tnx

Comment: P.P.S. Read this question better please.